# How to remove space in the beginning of phrase in php?

Tags: php

I want to remove the white space from the beginning and after of the phrase,

```html
$mystring = "           Test Business Group Co.,Ltd     ";
```

The white space before and after the words is randomly, so how could i remove the beginning and after  white spaces in php.The actual result is like this

```
$mystring = "Test Business Group Co.,Ltd";
```

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: `trim()` function.

Comment: trim($mystring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `trim()` function which removes white spaces from the beginning and end of a string: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```
$string = "   hello  world   ";
$better_string = trim($string);

-> "hello world"
```